# What is the best way to write Scala codes for "if else" logic?

Tags: scala

all,

I am new to Scala. And I want to implement following logic:

```
def func(): Boolean = {
  var a = true
  val b = "for some condition checking"
  if (b == "some value") {
    a = false
  }
  a
}
```

If I don't want to use "var", I may just write it like this?

```
def func(): Boolean = {
  val b = "for some condition checking"
  if (b == "some value") {
    false
  }
  true
}
```

Any better implementation in Scala? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please spend some time reading scala documentation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! I understand now matching is a good way to replace "if else" checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def func(): Boolean = {
  val b = "for some condition checking"
  b != "some value"
}
```

Comment: Yes, a quite simple and graceful sample!